# embed iframe doesn't returned responsive design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I make 2 iframe as below

```
<iframe src="http://www.caely.my" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://contest2015.bestasiaapp.hk/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=Y150153&gclid=CPOD2tGbosQCFVUMjgod-r8AAw" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ow0wy0jm/1/

The first one doesn't returned its responsive design, I wonder what's the problem. Then I tested with other site, the second one worked properly. If you resize http://www.caely.my which is the first site, it's acutally a respnsive site. How come in iframe it render desktop version instead?

Answer (score 1):

Both site you loaded are using 2 kind of responsive.

Caely site is using script to detect devices then load the different site.

While Best Asia App are responsive based on @media query CSS.

Iframe is not categorized into mobile devices, therefore you can't get the site to be responsive in the iframe. The script doesn't recognize iframe in mobile.